# Safari toolbar UI Design, How to integrate a add button like Safari does it?

Tags: cocoa, nstoolbar

Is there is a NSToolbar trick to integrate a add ("+") button in the right lower toolbar corner like Safari does it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an `NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController` with a `layoutAttribute` of `.Right`.

You can configure it with a view (e.g. the plus button view), and add the view controller to the window with `window.addTitlebarAccessoryViewController(NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController)`

Comment: Hi Taylor, thank you very much. I made it working. but the button is on the upper right side. Is there is a way to move them down to the lower right side? I added a ViewController and Class them to a subclass of `NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController`. than i add them like you said: `avc.layoutAttribute = NSLayoutAttribute.Right; window?.addTitlebarAccessoryViewController(avc)`. how to put them down?

Comment: to make the viewcontroller the height of the toolbar is and use autolayout pin to bottom, is a way that works. Is it the _right_ way?

Comment: Yeah, using auto layout to pin your view to the bottom is a good way to do that. NSWindow will automatically size the height of `.Right` accessory views to be the height of the whole titlebar area (titlebar+toolbar if shown), including updating it if the user hides the toolbar.